# Reactive stream Kafka Stream Fan-out to http actors

Tags: microservices, akka-http, akka-stream, apache-kafka-streams, reactive-streams

I'm very new to Akka Streaming and reactive streaming. I have a question: is it possible to have a rest API receiving a message dropping it on Kafka Bus, and the Kafka streaming consumer then aggregates the messages in a max. time window and retrun the answer back?

How to implement such a system? Or where to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rest API you can consider the Kafka REST Proxy: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest
Or course you can instead build your own using akka-http and akka-stream-kafka.

As to windowing, I'm sure it can be done in akka streams but personally, I'd suggest using Kafka Streams as the first port of call:
http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#windowing

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by returning the answer back, but if you follow the approach above, you can use use REST Proxy to consume the windowed-aggregated messages or you can build a REST service that queries the Kafka Streams state stores via the so-called "interactive queries". This post shows how to do it using javax.ws.rs: https://www.confluent.io/blog/unifying-stream-processing-and-interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka/ but for a reactive application you can do the same using akka-http instead (I'm implementing this exact thing on one of my projects).